# How to use values with units of measurement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is a good way to use e.g. temperatures in Ruby without getting confused about the units of measurement used?

Is there a commonly accepted way to deal with this problem?

What is the syntax so that this makes the most sense and is easy to read?

What is the best way to communicate which Units a given function expects or how to ensure that it gets the right ones?

Comment: What specifically do you find confusing about the units?  They aren't really optional, since they tell you whether you should wear a jacket or a tank top when someone says it's 40 out.

Comment: Well if I have a method `def jacket_needed?(temperature)` how to make sure the one writing the call actually uses the correct unit for the temperature he passes to the method as the method uses to determine if it is cold or not.

Comment: Short of Geocoding the user and determining what unit of measure they use I don't know how you could infer what unit of measure they are describing when they say 40. You could always just assume a unit of measure and present the unit to the user in the prompt. "What temperature in Ferienheight is it where you are?"

Comment: Most of the weather forecasting sites give you the option to set your units to F or C.  If you are dealing with an application that needs to deal with temperatures, you'll probably need to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The long answer would be to create a class for Temperature, then subclass it for Ferienheit, Celcius and Kelvin. And have them all implement a function that returns their value in one or the other.

So if you want to base your system off Ferienheit you could Have them all implement a toFerienheit method then regardless of what type of measurement you are taking you would always have method to get them back to one distilable temperature.

Thats the best I can do for this sort of vague question.

Comment: Hm I should probably have added that I wanted to know if there is a kind of common way to deal with this problem, as it seems to be rather general and I assumed a lot of people face it.

Comment: I would add to this that, if you're building a database-backed application, you need to decide which units will be stored in the database. For example, always store values in Celsius, and if the user requests a value in Fahrenheit, perform the conversion on the fly **after** you've retrieved the value from the database. I don't advise storing the value and the units in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, if you're asking for user input of temperature at some point in your application, you're also going to have to ask them for unit too. You *can't* rely on them always entering the correct value in C/F/K/whatever you decide to use.

In the background, you either do what has already been suggested, and pass Temperature objects, which can return the temperature in any unit, or be more diligent in your consistent use of a single unit and more explicit in your variable naming:

```
def jacket_needed?(celcius)
  celcius < 10
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a commonly accepted way to do that, but I would create a class to handle each measure. Eg.:

```
class Temperature
  def initialize value, unit = :K
    # convert the value into a internal unit, e.g. Kelvin,
    # to store internally
  end
  def value unit = :K
    # convert the value to the desired unit and return it.
  end
end

class Length
  def initialize value, unit = :m
    #...
  end
  #...
end

class TimeLength
  def initialize value, unit = :s
    #...
  end
  #...
end
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a gem that handles unit conversion and math -- [Unitwise](//github.com/joshwlewis/unitwise). It's based on the Unified Code for Units of Measure ([UCUM](//unitsofmeasure.org)), a standard for representing units in computer science. Unitwise can quantify, convert and perform math on many units, temperatures included:

```
require 'unitwise'

temp = 22.convert_to('degree Celsius') 
# => #<Unitwise::Measurement 22 degree Celsius>

temp.convert_to("degree Fahrenheit")
# => #<Unitwise::Measurement 71.59999999999997 degree Fahrenheit>
```

It also supports Kelvin and Rankine temperature scales.

Comment: Are there features that make your gem stand out from the ones listed in the accepted answer?

Comment: It's the only one that's based on [UCUM](//unitsofmeasure.org), which addresses a few of your concerns about accepted way of expressing units. The list of units and their conversion factors are maintained by an organization dedicated to doing so, not by me. That also comes with the advantage of a tremendous number of units.Also, it doesn't use monkey-patching by default